# Big integer not getting converted to String as expected in java

Tags: java, cryptography, tostring, biginteger

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt including XOR function. For certain set of inputs Big Integer is getting converted properly to encrypted text(cipher) and am able to decrypt it. But for certain set of inputs the Big Integer is not getting converted back to the encrypted text(cipher). I am trying to figure where am I going wrong.

Example (cipher getting converted back to encrypted text) Input : "client1"

*Encrypting...

Encrypted : **w]h"iÐÿ**

cipher text in binary: 111011101011101011010000010001001101001110100000001011111111111

Key used for XORing in binary: 100010111010101

XORed Cipher text in binary: 111011101011101011010000010001001101001110100000101001000101010

Key used for Inverse XORing in binary: 100010111010101

retrieved cipher text in binary after xoring111011101011101011010000010001001101001110100000001011111111111

Cipher Text retrieved back by xoring **w]h"iÐÿ**

Dencrypted : client1

Decrypted text: client1*

Example (Not getting converted to encrypted text) Input: "client2"

*Encrypting...

Encrypted : **5^ÉœÇZ!R**
 
cipher text in binary: 11010101011110110010010101001111000111010110100010000101010010

Key used for XORing in binary: 100010111010101

XORed Cipher text in binary: 11010101011110110010010101001111000111010110100110010010000111

Key used for Inverse XORing in binary: 100010111010101

retrieved cipher text in binary after xoring11010101011110110010010101001111000111010110100010000101010010

Cipher Text retrieved back by xoring **5^ÉSÇZ!R***

Here is my code.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import javax.crypto.*;

public class MainClass {
    private static String algorithm = "DESede";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String toEncrypt = "client2";

        System.out.println("Encrypting...");
        BigInteger encrypted1 = encrypt(toEncrypt, "password");

        String decrypted = decrypt(encrypted1, "password");
        System.out.println("Decrypted text: " + decrypted);

    }

    public static BigInteger XOR(String s) throws Exception {
        BigInteger message = convertStringToBigInteger(s);

        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        int seed = 10;
        random.setSeed(seed);

        byte[] keyStream = new byte[2];
        random.nextBytes(keyStream);
        BigInteger key = new BigInteger(keyStream);

        BigInteger cipherText = message.xor(key);
        System.out.println("cipher text in binary: " + message.toString(2));
        System.out.println("Key used for XORing in binary: " + key.toString(2));
        System.out.println("XORed Cipher text in binary: " + cipherText.toString(2));
        return cipherText;
    }

    public static String InverseXOR(BigInteger s) throws Exception {
        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
        int seed = 10;
        random.setSeed(seed);

        byte[] keyStream = new byte[2];
        random.nextBytes(keyStream); //generate random bytes in put in keyStream
        BigInteger key = new BigInteger(keyStream);

        BigInteger receivedMessage = s.xor(key);
        System.out.println("Key used for Inverse XORing in binary: " + key.toString(2));
        System.out.println("retrieved cipher text in binary after xoring" + receivedMessage.toString(2));
        String receivedMessageString = convertBigIntegerToString(receivedMessage);
        System.out.println("Cipher Text retrieved back by xoring " + receivedMessageString);
        return receivedMessageString;
    }

    private static String convertBigIntegerToString(BigInteger b) {
        String s = new String();
        while (b.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1) {
            BigInteger c = new BigInteger("11111111", 2);
            int cb = (b.and(c)).intValue();
            Character cv = new Character((char) cb);
            s = (cv.toString()).concat(s);
            b = b.shiftRight(8);
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static BigInteger convertStringToBigInteger(String s) {
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger("0");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            Integer code = new Integer((int) s.charAt(i));
            BigInteger c = new BigInteger(code.toString());
            b = b.shiftLeft(8);
            b = b.or(c);
        }
        return b;
    }

    public static BigInteger encrypt(String toEncrypt, String key) throws Exception {

        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
        kg.init(sr);
        SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);

        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sk);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt.getBytes());
        String encrypt = new String(encrypted);
        System.out.println("Encrypted : " + encrypt);
        BigInteger XoredData = XOR(encrypt);
        return XoredData;

    }

    public static String decrypt(BigInteger encrypted1, String key) throws Exception {
        String encryptedCipher = InverseXOR(encrypted1);
        byte[] encryptedByte = encryptedCipher.getBytes();

        SecureRandom sr = new SecureRandom(key.getBytes());
        KeyGenerator kg = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm);
        kg.init(sr);
        SecretKey sk = kg.generateKey();

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sk);
        byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encryptedByte);
        String decrypt = new String(decrypted);
        System.out.println("Dencrypted : " + decrypt);
        return decrypt;
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Please reduce your question to a minimal, complete, well-formatted example, with hardcoded inputs, the expected output as text, and the actual output as text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). You also should provide your question (including sample input and output) **as text**, not as images.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you. I have modified the question.

Comment: SecureRandom is not meant to be used as a stream cipher. It is possible for a compliant implementation of SecureRandom to produce non-deterministic output no matter whether you seed it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Issue 1:** (Portability)

Note that `SecureRandom(seed)` does not always depend on the seed.
The fact you get the same key when supplying the same seed almost 100% implies you're running this on Windows.

The construction you use in `XOR()` might be more portable.  I.e.

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG"); 
random.setSeed(seed);
```

**Issue 2:** (Maybe the source of what you're seeing)

From Javadoc for `String(byte [] bytes)`:

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset. [...]
>   The behavior of this constructor when the given bytes are not valid in the default charset is unspecified.

... and you're feeding it cipertext, which may contain such invalid byte sequences.

You might want to test whether `Arrays.equals(new String(encrypted).getBytes(), encrypted)` to see if you're losing anything in the conversion.  If you absolutely have to have it be a `String` then look at "base64 encoding".  It is designed exactly for the purpose of converting arbitrary bytes into legal character encodings.

Alternatively, you might wish to leave your ciphertext as an array of bytes, or perhaps initialize a `BigInteger` using the `BigInteger(byte [])` constructor.

One aditional word of caution: Note that BigInteger is a *signed* bigint class, so the `toByteArray` method may prepend a leading zero if necessary to disambiguate a positive value that has its MSb set.  This requires some handling, but can be predicted by comparing the `BigInteger` against `BigInteger.ZERO`.

**Issue 3:** (Portability)

This line in `convertStringToBigInteger` assumes 8-bit *characters*.

```
b.shiftLeft(8);
```

`byte`s are 8-bit in Java, but characters can be 8 or 16 bits, and I would not be surprising to see an update to allow 32-bit unicode `char`s as well.

It would be safer to iterate over the result of `String#getBytes()`...or better yet, skip the conversion to string, and leave the intermediates as byte arrays, or `BigIntegers` (using  BigInteger#toByteArray)

**Minor Things**

You can use `BigInteger.ZERO` instead of `new BigInteger("0")`

We'll be able to read your code easier if you indent it.